# Electromagnitism

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics

I'm a High school student new to physics but very intrigued. Now I do not have much knowledge on electromagnetism or physics but is it possible for electromagnetic fields to be focused into a form? Not a beam or a signal but a shape.

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic fields make shapes all the time. For example, you can put iron filings near a magnet and see how the field lines curve around it. You can focus a high power laser into a point so that its electric field makes a spark floating in the air in the middle of nowhere or wherever you want it.  You can't make things like force fields, tangible holograms, and lightsabers, though.